# Factor $x^8 - x$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[x].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, integers

I know $x^8 - x = x(x^7 - 1)$ and the roots of $x^7 -1$ are the 7th roots of unity, but 6 of those roots are complex. I'm pretty sure this can be factored further, but I don't know how to think of it in the integers.

Comment: Hint: one of those roots is $1$.

Comment: So it's just $x(x-1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$? I think I can show that the last part is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, that's the complete factorization.

Comment: $x(x-1)\Phi_7(x)$, where $\Phi_7(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by applying Eisenstein's criterion (wrt $p=7$) to $\Phi_7(x+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$
x^{n}-1= \prod _{d\mid n}\Phi _{d}(x)
$$
where $\Phi _{d}(x)$ is the $d$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).
Therefore,
$$
x^8 - x = x(x^7-1) = x \, \Phi _{1}(x) \, \Phi _{7}(x) = x(x-1)((x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
$$
When $p$ is prime, we have
$$
\Phi_p(x) = x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x + 1
$$
whose irreducibility follows from Eisenstein's criterion applied to $\Phi_p(x+1)$.